# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:8773

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure

I am new to asp.net, I have create and hosted a simple website using three tier architecture on azure, I am trying to use a wcf service in the web page, in the local i am able to use the webservice without any error but when I publish it on azure and run it, I am getting the below error, it would be great if any one could help me solving the problem,

I tried googling it but did not find an answer.FYI there is no default proxy in the web.config file.

> ERROR : An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:8773

Comment: see if this helps : http://martininghamsoftdev.blogspot.com/2011/07/wcf-communicationexception-exception.html

Comment: also you could use `netstat -o` to find what process is blocking the port(if any).

Comment: Sounds like your web app and wcf service are hosted in the same VM. Is it? AFAIK, more recent versions of windows prevent loopback connections for security reasons. It's a guess.. (IMHO, not enough information in the question) but if that's what you are doing, try not to club together the site and the service in the same role.